# Glob syntax documentation

Tags: visual-studio-code

there are some options, in the settings (like "files.exclude", etc.), which presume using "globs". I couldn't find documentation for syntax of these globs, however. Can you add the glob patterns syntax description to your site?

Comment: There is some glob documentation here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options.

Comment: yeah, that was the only piece of documentation about those globs that I could find on the whole site… I'd probably need more examples. too many questions: if I need to exclude the whole dir (e.g., `{projectRoot}/var/run`), for example, what would i use:
1. var/run
2. ./var/run
3. var/run/*
4. var/run/**
?

Comment: `**/run` would be enough if you had a single `run` folder to exclude.  If you had more and wanted to narrow it down then `**/var/run` would work.

Comment: Even if I can manage to concoct some glob pattern with a "pretty much unique" match, as a programmer it sort of offends me that I can't set a *definitely absolute* path if all I wanted was to match one single file to begin with.